# Text background not working with html2canvas

Tags: javascript, html2canvas

I am trying to generate a picture from my Div using Html2Canvas but it is not working fine, The problem is the background on my text. You can see that here:

```js
window.takeScreenShot = function() {
  html2canvas(document.getElementById("est1"), {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
      document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    },
    width: 320,
    height: 220
  });
}
```

```css
#example4 {
  display: block;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font-family: Arial;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(213, 11, 27), rgb(28, 79, 145));
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id="est1" style="display: block;">
  <h3 id="example4" data-text="Test" class="tt">Test</h3>
</div>
<button onclick="takeScreenShot()">to image</button>
```

I have a text background style and it shows fine the text, but if You click on <kbd>To Image</kbd>, `html2canvas` generate a picture with a black text and wrong background.

How I can do to generate a correct picture using `html2canvas`?

Comment: They probably just don't support `background-clip: text` yet.

Comment: any solution for this one?

Answer (score -1):

Try to use CSS as **inline** and you can generate a correct Picture using html2canvas.

```
<h3 data-text="Test" class="tt" style="display: block; font-size: 60px;color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Arial;background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(213, 11, 27), rgb(28, 79, 145));-webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; -webkit-background-clip: text; -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;">Test</h3>
```

Comment: @luis urdaneta please try this solution, might be you got your answer.